# Select two rows that are closest to a given value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the below table in **MS Access.**

```html
Day    ABC
365     25
548     35
730     37 
913     58 
1095    146
```

I want to query it such that I get the row before and after a given value of the Day column. This value is variable and can be e.g. **value = 432**
For this example the query would result the following table.

```html
Day    ABC
365     25
548     35
```

Because the given value = 432 is larger than the Day value of 365 and smaller than the Day value of 548.

What I managed to do is get one field, but not both. The following query gave me correct rows of the Day field.

```
    Select Max(Day) As Day From Table Where Day < 432
    UNION
    Select Min(Day) As Day  From Table Where Day > 432
```

When I use this code and add another field like ABC I get an error.

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression 'ABC' as part of an aggregate function.

Could you help me? I think this should be a really easy task. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your SQL.  The error message occurs because you didn't add a `GROUP BY ABC` clause to both the `SELECT` statements.
You'll also get a circular reference as due to `MAX(DAY) as DAY` - you need to change the `as Day` to something else maybe `as lDay`.
You'll probably (I did) get a error Syntax Error calling it `Table` - pretty sure that's a reserved word.

Maybe this query will work better:

```
Select Top 1 Day, ABC From Table3 Where Day <= 913 ORDER BY Day Desc
UNION ALL
Select Top 1 Day, ABC From Table3 Where Day >= 913 ORDER BY Day Asc
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! However this would always give me the first row of the table (regardless of the value) and some other row. For a value of 745 I would like to get rows 730 and 913 and not 365 and some other row

Comment: You're absolutely correct - my apologies.  Add `ORDER BY Day Desc` to the end of the first `SELECT` statement and `ORDER BY Day Asc` to the second statement.  In addition, if you select an exact value; say 913 it will return a single value as `UNION` automatically removes duplicates, to return two rows (which will both be identical) use `UNION ALL`.  I'll update my answer to show the Asc and Desc sorting.

Comment: The error has nothing to to with the word Table, I just used it to illustrate the example. The actual tableis named differently

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot! Could you please update your answer again to "UNION ALL". Thanks for this info it helped me and I guess others will also find this info useful

Answer (score 0):

You could also be a little fancier:

```
Select Top 2 Day, ABC From Table3 Order By Abs(Day - 432) Desc
```

Note please, that the result will match the *title* of the question, not necessarily your detailed explanation ...